# SQLAlchemy problems with foreign keys and association tables

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a link between a person, a company and an email address the person is using at the given company.

In SQL terms I think this would be four tables, Person, Company, Email and email_company_association, with two FKs in email_company_association, one to email and one to company. And then one FK in Email to Person. An Email-address can be connected directly to a person as well, hence the Person FK in Email.

I am however a bit at a loss how to do this in SQLAlchemy.

I have tried something like:

```
class Person(Base):
    """
    A person
    """
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('person_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    surename = Column(String(255))
    forename = Column(String(255))

class Company(Base):
    """
    A company
    """
    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('company_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email_addresses = relationship("Company_Email_Association", backref="company")
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False)
    person = relationship("Person", backref=backref('companies', order_by=id))

class Email(Base):
    """
    Email address
    """
    __tablename__ = 'emailaddresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False)
    person = relationship("Person", backref=backref('emailaddresses', order_by=id)) 

class Company_Email_Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company_email_assoc'
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('companies.id'), primary_key=True)
    email_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('emailaddresses.id'), primary_key=True)
    email = relationship("Email")
```

I am using this ca. like so:

```
p = Person()
c = Company(name="Foo LTD")
cea = Company_Email_Association()
cea.email = Email(email="foo@example.org") # This breaks since Email needs persons.id
c.email_addresses.append(cea)
p.companies.append(c)
```

This is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "person_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, foo@example.org, null).
 'INSERT INTO emailaddresses (email, person_id) VALUES (%(email)s, %(person_id)s) RETURNING emailaddresses.id' {'person_id': None,'email': 'foo@example.org'}
```

I am guessing I am doing both the SQLAlchemy and the modelling very wrong, but I am at a loss at what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the model and database classes was correct, but my usage of them wasnt. Using the following code seems to do what I want.

```
p = Person()
c = Company(name="Foo LTD")
cea = Company_Email_Association()
cea.email = Email(email="foo@example.org") # This breaks since Email needs persons.id
p.emailaddresses.append(cea.email)
c.email_addresses.append(cea)
p.companies.append(c)
```

Adding the Email address to the Person object was crucial.